# Error deploying yii2-starter-kit Yii2 installation

Tags: web-services, yii2

I'm trying to deploy this Yii2 installation (https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/installation.md#configure-your-web-server) but I'm having problems.
I think problems are related with this configuration step: "Configure your web server".

I've the webpage running here: http://vector5.raspctl.com/yii2-starter-kit/frontend/web/

But no one of the options works. For example, "Connect" option (http://vector5.raspctl.com/yii2-starter-kit/frontend/web/user/sign-in/login)

I can't found the error, any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not the standard installation (basic or advanced) from Yii2 installation. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Yii2-Starter-Kit is not ready to work in a single-domain installation. You must enable, for example: backend.website.com, storage.website.com and the frontpage www.website.com

The [installation guide](https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/installation.md), specifies this.

You can [use this guide](https://github.com/mickgeek/yii2-advanced-one-domain-config), to setup your single-domain installation (remember that the yii2-starter-kit also uses the storage folder!).

Have a great week.